# Why does the following class require a destructor? How to add one?

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
public:
    Person()
    {
        numberOfchildren = 0;
        children = new string[20];
    }
    void addAChild(string name)
    {
        children[numberOfchildren++] = name;
    }
    string *getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }
    int getNumberOfChildren()
    {
        return numberOfchildren;
    }
private:
    string *children;
    int numberOfchildren;
};
#endif
```

Comment: The code as posted is a class definition. It does not require a destructor, so a main assertion in the question is incorrect. Post a complete but minimal example that demonstrates the problem, and remember to describe the problem.

Comment: It "requires" a destructor in the sense that you would be leaking memory otherwise. However, there's no need for `new` if you are just allocating a fixed-size array. `string children[20];` is sufficient.

Comment: Or, since you don't even check for being out of bounds, perhaps a `std::vector<std::string>` so it can grow as needed (also no need to use `new`)

Comment: Also, if you ever need a destructor, you most probably need to manually handle the copy constructor and assignment operator as well. The default copy would copy the raw pointer and when even one of them gets deallocated, it will deallocate the memory and all the remaining objects would be left with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The class needs a destructor because it allocates an array of strings on the heap in the constructor.

If the class goes out of scope without deleting that array of strings, you will have a memory leak.

edit: you should consider using an `std::vector` instead. Just call `vector<T>::resize(size_t)` to set the initial size.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you would use standard class `std::vector<std::string>` instead of the manually allocated array. For example

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
public:
    Person()
    {
    }

    void addAChild( const string &name )
    {
        children.push_back( name );
    }
    vector<string> getChildren() const
    {
        return children;
    }
    int getNumberOfChildren() const
    {
        return children.size();
    }
private:
    vector<string> children;
};
#endif
```

In this case it is enough to have implicitly defined destructor.

As for your code then you have to release allocated memory for array children. So the destructor will look like

```
~Person()
{
    delete []children;
}
```

Take into account that if you return pointer in method `getChildren` then everybody can change children of any person.

Answer (score 0):

This class requires a destructor because it contains a pointer (the array of children) to an object allocated on the heap. Without destructor, when an instance of this class is deleted, the children array remains in memory: this is called a **memory leak**.

To create the destructor, simply add the method `~Person()` to the class members

```
~Person()
{
    delete[] children;
}
```

Comment: Wrong delete use delete[]

Comment: Wrong deleter.  Anyway, yes, this will deallocate the memory, but it is a completely unsafe way to write a class.  What happens when an object is copied?  Rule of three, rule of five...

Comment: Also, destructors should be `virtual`.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking you're right, answer updated. Ed S. is also right, this is a very simple class example, and is not safe for many use cases

Comment: @bereal no need to be virtual if it's not a base class

Comment: @chunkyguy you never know for sure if it's a base class or not.